# Can some on please explain this graph of photo current vs. Cathode plate potential?

Tags: energy, electric-current, photoelectric-effect

http://cdn.dronstudy.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/106.jpg

Note that for large values of V, the current reaches a max value, corresponding to the case where all photo electrons are collected at anode.
In addition, the I increases as the incident light Intensity increases, as you might expect.
Finally when the V is negative, i.e when the battery is reversed, the photo electrons are repelled by negative plate A. Only those electron having a K.E higher than eV will reach A, where e is the charge on the electron. 
Furthermore, if V is greater than or equal to Vo, called the stopping potential, no electrons will reach A and the current will be zero.
The stopping potential is independent of the radiation intensity. The max K.E of the photoelectrons is related to the stopping potential through the relation, K.E(max)= eVo
that is what my book says.
I want to know how to read that graph. Also tell the meaning of the first line, starting with "Note that..."

Comment: What do want to know by " how to read the graph "

Comment: I cannot see the text only the graph. What don't you understand - it all seems pretty straight forward on first glance?